# Jenkins Karate pipeline project could not execute maven goal

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, karate

Error message from the Jenkins console:

> The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no
> POM in this directory
> (/home/jenkins/workspace/Dealer-API-v2-test-automation_qa). Please
> verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Maven command in the Jenkins file:

> sh script : "mvn test '-Dkarate.options=--tags @regression' -Dtest=TestParallel -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=qa'"

How can I execute this maven command in my pipeline script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but if you add `-f Dealer-API-v2-test-automation_qa/pom.xml` or something like that, it may start working. Or do a `cd Dealer-API-v2-test-automation_qa`, before doing `mvn test`, hope that helps.